# raising events using event Action<T>

Tags: c#, event-handling, action

I'm used to using delegate EventHandler for event callbacks but now I'm attempting to use event Action for invoking events. I couldn't find much info on how this can be used properly anywhere so I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

I have an Action event handler that handles string objects. In my subscriber class I have `public event Action<string> UploadProgress;`. The event handler is invoked like this:

```
UploadProgress.Invoke(string.Format("sending file data {0:0.000}%", (bytesSoFar * 100.0f) / totalToUpload));
```

The listener class is subscribed to this event as below:

```
uploadFile.UploadProgress += uploadFile_UploadProgress;
void uploadFile_UploadProgress(string obj)
{
  var prog = obj;
}
```

When the event is invoked, I get `System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object`. I'm not sure what I need to change in the subscriber class to avoid this error. Can someone tell me the proper way to use event Action or provide me the link to where I can read up on it? I know how to use the normal Action but confused about declaring it as an event. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way is much better, send bytesToUpload and totalToUpload through event, instead of the whole Action (right sample):

```
  internal class Program
  {
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      SomeClass someClass = new SomeClass();
      someClass.UploadProgress += SomeClass_UploadProgress;
      someClass.DoSomeUpload();
    }

    private static void SomeClass_UploadProgress(object sender, UploadEventArgs e)
    {
      string s = string.Format("sending file data {0:0.000}%", (e.BytesSoFar * 100.0f) / e.TotalToUpload);
      Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
  }

  public class UploadEventArgs : EventArgs
  {
    public float BytesSoFar { get; set; }
    public float TotalToUpload { get; set; }
  }

  public class SomeClass
  {
    public event EventHandler<UploadEventArgs> UploadProgress;

    public void DoSomeUpload()
    {
      if (UploadProgress != null)
      {
        UploadEventArgs e = new UploadEventArgs();
        e.BytesSoFar = 123f;
        e.TotalToUpload = 100000f;
        UploadProgress.Invoke(this, e);
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Do I need to have an EventHandler in place? can't I just use public event Action<string> UploadProgress?

Comment: why is UploadProgress always null? The code inside the block never gets executed.

Comment: Appreciate your effort to resolve my issue. I've understood your code and it's probably the right way to do it but my issue is this. UploadProgress is always null so the action event is never invoked. I don't have a DoSomeUpload() method inside my code rather the upload process is run on the go and I'm trying to track the upload progress and raise the event inside the while loop that is sending bytes to the server. Should I provide you the full code to make better sense of it?

Comment: But action.Invoke will be called only when UploadProgress isn't null which isn't the case. If I remove that then I get NullReferenceException. So should the handler first be initialized before I try to invoke it? The event listener just waits for the event to be raised which it never does due to the action handler never being invoked.

Comment: ohh okay cool. I think I understood what u meant. I'll give it a try. Thanks :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116853/discussion-between-ahmed-mujtaba-and-x).

Comment: That's not what the OP asked though. He never wanted a replacement method, he just wanted the one he had to be tweaked.